# Unable to visualise PointCloud in Rviz (ROS) from publisher and subscriber node

Tags: c++, ros, point-cloud-library

I am using the below code for publisher and subscriber. I am able to visualise PointCloud on Rviz for input node but failed to visualise output node. As i am quite new in ROS. How i can solve the problem? I have even  set in Rviz the Fixed Frame: base_link.

```
ros::Subscriber subPointCloud;
ros::Publisher pubPointCloud;

void DEM(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
{
  ROS_DEBUG("Point Cloud Received");
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 output;

  // Convert from ROS message to PCL point cloud
  pcl::fromROSMsg(*input, *cloud);
  pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud, output);

  output.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
  output.header.frame_id = "/baselink";
  pubPointCloud.publish(output);

  }


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ROS_INFO("Starting LIDAR Node");
  ros::init(argc, argv, "kitti_lidar_node");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;

  subPointCloud = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("input", 1, DEM);
  pubPointCloud = nh.advertise<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> > ("output", 1);

  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you already tried to set the frame id without a slash like `"base_link"`?

Comment: yes, i tried with both way but unfortunately did't workout.

Comment: What does `rostopic echo /input` and `rostopic echo /output` give you on the terminal. Does the point cloud appears if you just resend the input?

Comment: after running both command in terminal, i don't see anything. Just command runs no output.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you have set your fixed frame in RViz to `base_link`, but in your code you set the `frame_id` of the output message to `baselink`(notice the missing underscore). You can solve this issue twofold: Either publish the other output with the same frame id (i.e. `base_link`) or provide a [transformation](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) from `base_link` to `baselink` via e.g. commandline:

```
$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 base_link baselink 1000
```

Comment: Hi Tiko, I tried with command line but still same. Also i tried with changing frame_id ="base_link" but no luck.

Comment: What is the last parameter (1000) in the command for? I don’t find it in the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20static%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps to troubleshoot...
 1. First check on command line that the output is actually being populated by running:`rostopic echo /output`, make sure that the array is actually being populated.
 2. Make sure that the TF tree between the fixed frame in RVIZ and the message frame_id is complete. You can check it by adding a TF tree:  Click add > By Display types > rviz > TF.
Then open the tree by expanding TF > then clicking on tree.
If there is an issue this should help identify it.
 3. Finally check the status of the pointcloud message by expanding the Status.

Comment: i have added TF and tree seems look fine, as you can see in the second picture which i have added in the question. But still /output pointcloud not able to see. Further, `rostopic echo /output` runs but does not give any output. Kindly help me to solve the issue.

Comment: So I think you first need to get the messages to come through.  If you don't see it in commandline, then somehow the publisher is not publishing correctly. When you run the node do you see the `ROS_DEBUG("Point Cloud Received")` messages?  If you don't see them, try changing it to `ROS_INFO("Point Cloud Received");`